# Summarize values from text file in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I am trying to make a summary of a text file, but there is one twist I cannot manage. I have several rows and I want to get the averages of the values in consecutive rows from the same category. When the category changes I want a new line in the resulting summary.

The text file looks like this (text.txt):

```
1 1 a
2 2 a
3 3 a
4 4 b
5 5 b
6 6 a
7 7 a
8 8 b
```

Ok, and I want to have this (counter, category, average 1, average 2):

```
1 a 2.0 2.0
1 b 4.5 4.5
2 a 6.5 6.5
2 b 8.0 8.0
```

I got so far but that only summarizes everything:

```
cat test.txt | awk '{avg1+=$1;avg2+=$2;cat=$3;count++}END{print "1",cat,avg1/count,avg2/count}
```

This is the result:

```
1 b 4.5 4.5
```

So, what can I do to get this right? How to make it realize, that the category changes? One liner would be great. Thx!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide us with an input and output that match - at the moment, it looks like they're unrelated. In terms of solving your problem, what you need to do is change `avg1` and `avg2` to arrays.

Comment: Thx for the hint, Tom, but I think I provided matching input and output in regard to what I want. Not sure, if I just don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The post was enough documented for me to find the problem (at least, I think)

Comment: The input you have shown has numbers up to 8 but it's not clear to me where these are shown in the desired output.

Comment: They are averaged over the category avg1=1+2+3 (should have been sum1 better) and then in the result I get avg1/count(=3)=2.0. Maybe I could have used random numbers as well, but I thought, it was clear. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The END tag in AWK is only executed at the end of your input. That is why you only have a single line. If you want to print for every change, you have to check if the line changed and print the result as they change.

You can use this script to do it:

```
FNR == 1{
    previousChar = $3;
    round=1;
}

{
    if ( previousChar != $3 ) {
        print int((round+1)/2),cat,avg1/count,avg2/count;
        avg1=0.0;
        avg2=0.0;
        count=0;
        round++;
        previousChar=$3;
    } 
    avg1+=$1; 
    avg2+=$2; 
    cat=$3; 
    count++
} 

END { 
    print int((round+1)/2),cat,avg1/count,avg2/count
}
```

You still have to print the last end in the the END tag.

One advantage of AWK scripts is that you can use it on one line like this:

```
cat test.txt | awk 'FNR == 1{previousChar = $3;round=1;}{if ( previousChar != $3 ) {      print int((round+1)/2),cat,avg1/count,avg2/count;avg1=0.0;avg2=0.0;count=0;round++;previousChar=$3;}avg1+=$1;avg2+=$2;cat=$3;count++} END {print int((round+1)/2),cat,avg1/count,avg2/count}'
```

Output example with your input:

```
1 a 2 2
1 b 4.5 4.5
2 a 6.5 6.5
2 b 8 8
```

**Edit: added version of cowhi**

Comment: ok, that's already close. Thank you! Now I just need to have a counter for each switch basically like in the example result and the floats that should be the result of the division.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. If you update your answer with what is missing, I'll accept it as best answer: cat test.txt | awk 'FNR == 1{previousChar = $3;round=1;}{if ( previousChar != $3 ) {print int((round+1)/2),cat,avg1/count,avg2/count; avg1=0; avg2=0; count=0; round++; previousChar=$3;} avg1+=$1; avg2+=$2; cat=$3; count++} END { print int((round+1)/2),cat,avg1/count,avg2/count}'